# How to get the function name from base.odex with address and offset

Tags: android, addr2line

Here is an android app crash stacktrace:

F DEBUG : #05 pc 001d0949 /data/app/com.test-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x12a000)

I know for ".so" library, I can use addr2line to get the function name.

So how to deal with odex files?

Comment: Did you find how this can be done? I am also interested in a solution.

Comment: @user1592546 no.